# How do I get a list of files in a folder client-side using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, filesystems

Is there a way I could get, in form of an array or something, a list of files in a folder of my choice? It must be in the local user filesystem. Client-side.

I'm trying to make something like a Diary that can list previous entries made by the user in a specific folder.

If I won't have to use jQuery and the like, it'd be better.

Also, mainly supposed to work on Firefox and Chrome, I don't really need other browsers. No other devices than a PC involved as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to create a plugin for those browsers, as Javascript alone is not allowed to access client-side filesystem. The alternative is to create a Java applet and offer an option to launch the applet via Java Web Start.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you must you have to use ssh connexion so you can get clients files.